# Why do I get this error when I mount a machine using SSHFS?

Tags: mount, sshfs

I thought I asked about this before, but I can't find it.

I have a computer called "Mythbuntu" that is on my LAN. When I first boot the computer I work from, I see an entry for "Mythbuntu" in my "Places" menu, like so:

[image: Mythbuntu menu one]

When I click on it, I get this error message:

[image: Mythbuntu error]

However, once I dismiss it, there are two entries for my Mythbuntu computer in the "Places" menu, where the bottom one is the one that works:

[image: Mythbuntu menu two]

This is my entry in `/etc/fstab` for the Mythbuntu computer, which I adapted from some tutorial somewhere on the net:

```
sshfs#mythbuntu@192.168.0.4:/home/mythbuntu    /home/dave/Mythbuntu    fuse    comment=sshfs,user,noauto,transform_symlinks
```

How can I set it up so that my Mythbuntu computer mounts on boot without having any error messages or having to click on a menu entry to activate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Change `noauto` to `auto` -- right now you've explicitly disabled auto-mount!

   - and add `Batchmode=yes`
2. Mounting sshfs via `/etc/fstab` may fail if no network connection exists at that point.

   - If you have that problem, [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=5635104&postcount=3) details a fairly concise way of setting up `ifup/ifdown` scripts that will mount/unmount sshfs upon network link up/down.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Unfortunately, when I make the changes you suggest, particularly changing noauto to auto, it results in an error message on the splash screen on boot. It says "There was an error mounting /home/mythbuntu, press S to skip or M to manually edit" (or something like that). The Mythbuntu machine is definitely available on the network, so maybe there's something else I need to do?

Comment: The problem is that at that point in the boot process, the *network* is not available on your machine. Please look at the link I posted and see if that works (up/down scripts)

Comment: Yep, I looked at the link and I set up the up down scripts, but I still get the error message. Actually, I just confirmed that even though I press "S" to skip, the Mythbuntu machine does actually successfully mount. So that's good. It would just be perfect if there was no error message along the way.

Comment: Since this answer resolved the initial issue, I've marked this as correct, but I've started another question about the problem in the boot process: http://askubuntu.com/q/157859/17041