# How do I get rid of the drive mount confirmation question for sshFS on boot?

Tags: boot, sshfs, fuse

With [help from this site](https://askubuntu.com/q/156196/17041), I was able to set up an SSHFS connection between two computers on my LAN so that one auto mounts on the other at boot time.

Everything works, but there is this annoying confirmation that comes up whenever I boot:

[image: sshfs boot confirmation]

> An error occurred while mounting /home/dave/Mythbuntu.
>
> Press S to skip mounting or M or Manual recovery

If I press <kbd>S</kbd>, then booting continues, and my drive is mounted as hoped, so it seems like even though I "skipped" it, maybe it tried again and succeeded later in the boot process.

I followed the instructions [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=5635104&postcount=3) to set up "if up / if down" scripts, and here is my current `/etc/fstab`:

```
sshfs#mythbuntu@192.168.0.4:/home/mythbuntu    /home/dave/Mythbuntu    fuse    auto,users,exec,uid=1000,gid=1000,allow_other,reconnect,transform_symlinks,BatchMode=yes 0 0
```

Although the mounting is working, this step of having to press <kbd>S</kbd> every time I boot is obviously kind of a hassle. How do I configure my computer so I don't have to do that, and so that my other computer will still automount?

Comment: try unmounting and mounting it manually in a console to see what error messages it gives `sudo umount ~/Mythbuntu` then `sudo mount ~/Mythbuntu`

Comment: @carlosz: When I remount, it says `read: Connection reset by peer`.

Comment: If you set up the scripts, please try changing the option to `noauto` in *fstab*.

Comment: @izx: That worked. Put that as an answer and you've got some rep.

Comment: Dave, glad to know; done. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've set up the `ifup/ifdown` scripts to bring SSHFS up/down with your network interface, there is no need for the system to attempt to mount it at boot via `/etc/fstab`; the drive still mounts because the *ifup* script is called after plain `mount` fails but before you get to your desktop.

The solution is simply to replace the `auto` option for SSHFS in `/etc/fstab` with `noauto`.